# How to prevent users from viewing apex code?

Tags: apex, class, permissions

There are many apex classes and triggers in my production org.  Despite 'System Administrator' being the only enabled profile, (in Develop>>Apex Classes>>"Class Name">>Security) users can still view code within the class.

Why can users view code despite their profile not being enabled to do so?

Comment: so how did you resolve this issue? can you please share your thoughts?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The visibility of the Apex classes is controlled by the system permission 'View Setup and Configuration’ on the user's profile. There is currently no option to make that more granular and e.g. exclude APEX code from the 'View Setup and Configuration'.

The 'Security' on Apex classes defines which users/profiles can *run* the code. More info on that here:
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_package_security.htm&language=en_US

Comment: so, how to prevent an user viewing the content of an apex class? do we have a solution now? I know this question was asked 5 years ago

Comment: @bforce remove their " 'View Setup and Configuration’ " permission is the only way to accomplish that, as indicated in the answer.

Comment: Thanks Guy, it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent apex classes and triggers viewing by users using profile level permissions

Comment: goto manageapps>profiles>select the user profile>and disable them

Comment: I'm guessing that's not really an option.  Yes, disabling a user would disallow them access to Apex Classes, but then they are disabled, and cannot use the system.  I believe the poster is asking for a way to do this while keeping the user active so they can still use the system.

Comment: Which profile level permission would they need to use?

Comment: what u are saying is users are viewing the apex class or u want want restrict them access to see the classes or even though the users are restricted their  access to see the classes but still they viewing the classes

Comment: Users should not be able to view code within classes. Doesn't matter if they see the name of the class; however they should get insufficient privileges error if they click on the name.